# How to prevent requests to server every page load

Tags: javascript

I wanted to know if there is a way to stop Javascript from calling a php every page and populating an array, and instead just carry the array accross all the pages the user browsers.

Currently every page load it makes a new reqest to the server and repopulates the array for example when a user clicks  link on a html page.

This is what i have in my JS file:

```
//Browser Support Code
function call_data(url,data){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {              
    AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest();              
  } else {                                  
    AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (AJAX) {
  querystring = "?dta="+data;
     AJAX.open("GET", url + querystring, false);                             
     AJAX.send(null);
     return AJAX.responseText;                                         
  } else {
     return false;
  }                                             
}       


var statistics = JSON.parse(call_data('user_info.php',userid));//user data
```

I don't currently see an advantage if its calling every page load, as I might as well do without ... unless theres a way to keep my array set each page load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [HTML5 Local Storage](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Web Storage / DOM Storage API through JavaScript. It has decent browser support and if you implement it properly you can always fall through to requesting the PHP page if Web Storage is not available.

Here is a tutorial to get you started:

http://www.diveintojavascript.com/tutorials/web-storage-tutorial-creating-an-address-book-application

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a cookie and check if the value in the cookie is valid, load it from cookie, otherwise request it from the server and save it in the cookie for future use.